# How do I auto-start Xen guests on boot?

Tags: 12.04, server, xen

I have just upgraded to Ubuntu Server 12.04 and permanently run a Xen guest.

We have migrated to the `xl` toolstack for Xen (from `xm`) as suggested which unlike `xm` does not have support for managed domains. `xm` is being removed in Xen 4.2 so I need to migrate away.

How should I configure my host to autostart Xen guests?

Answer (score 10):

There is a best practice in place & it has nothing to do with xl:

Do `>nano /etc/default/xendomains`
then deactivate VM restore using
XENDOMAINS_RESTORE=false & save

Then, create the subfolder auto underneath the /xen folder.

```
mkdir -p /etc/xen/auto

cd /etc/xen/auto
```

create a symlink to the virtual machine that you want to auto start at Dom0 boot & don't forget the dot at the end of the command

`ln -s /etc/xen/yourvm.cfg .`

Reboot

I asked to disable the restore feature because i had problems with it.

Answer (score 4):

## The Short Answer

To load all config files on boot link the `auto` folder directly to `/etc/xen`:

```
ln -s /etc/xen/ /etc/xen/auto
```

To load only specific config files link each individually:

```
mkdir -p /etc/xen/auto
ln -s /etc/xen/MY_DOMU_GUEST_1.cfg /etc/xen/auto/
ln -s /etc/xen/MY_DOMU_GUEST_2.cfg /etc/xen/auto/
```

## Explanation

There's a lesser-known `xen` config file `/etc/default/xendomains`.

There you can find in the comments documentation for three default settings:

```
XENDOMAINS_SAVE=/var/lib/xen/save
XENDOMAINS_RESTORE=true
XENDOMAINS_AUTO=/etc/xen/auto
```

To summarize the docs:

- `XENDOMAINS_SAVE` causes the VMs to be saved on a proper `reboot`.
- `XENDOMAINS_RESTORE` causes the VMs to be brought back up from the saved state when saved (whether saved manually with `xl save` or due to host reboot).
- `XENDOMAINS_AUTO` specifies a folder from which to load configs for VMs when no save state exists (i.e. `XENDOMAINS_SAVE` is disabled or there was a power failure or explicit `shutdown` instead of a `reboot`)

If you create the `auto` folder under `/etc/xen` and give it symlinks to the config file of the virtual machine (DomU guest) you'd like to start on physical machine (Dom0 host) then generally speaking they'll restore from the saved state that happens during the physical (host) server on reboot, but when that isn't available (such as after a shutdown or power failure or crash), they'll still load anyway.

If you'd rather always have the VMs shutdown on reboot rather than save state you can set `XENDOMAINS_SAVE=` and `XENDOMAINS_RESTORE=false`.

## The Old Way

It used to be that where there is now `on_shutdown`, `on_reboot`, and `on_crash` that you could also configure `on_xend_start = 'start'` and
`on_xend_stop = 'shutdown'`... but those are not the current practice.

Current (apply to the VM state itself):

```
on_shutdown = 'destroy'
on_reboot = 'restart'
on_crash = 'restart'
```

Ignored / Deprecated (apply to the host state):

```
on_xend_start = 'start'
on_xend_stop = 'shutdown'
```

Answer (score 0):

[www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/xen/users/259014](http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/xen/users/259014) suggests to me that Xen 4.1 with `xl` is unfortunately not a great combination.

The "fix" is to go back to `xm` until Xen 4.2 is packed in Ubuntu, at which point `xendomains` won't depend on `xend`, so you can start guests at boot and use `xl`.